# Percentage in one query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've tried to combine these two query to produce a percentage value.

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, regdate)) AS rdate, 
       COUNT(*) as sum 
FROM TBL where regdate > '2013-02-21' 
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, regdate)) 
ORDER BY rdate DESC 

SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, slutdatum)) AS sdate, 
       COUNT(*) as sum 
FROM TBL 
WHERE slutdatum > '2013-02-21' 
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, slutdatum))       
ORDER BY sdate DESC
```

But i really don't get it. I've tried like shown below but that only produce a error, the two query works by It's own; (I could run the queries separated and do the math after getting the values but that only seams to overdo it).

```
SELECT (SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, regdate)) AS rdate, count(*) as sum 
        FROM TBL where regdate > '2013-02-21' 
        GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, regdate)) 
        ORDER BY rdate DESC) / (select DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, slutdatum)) AS sdate,    
COUNT(*) as sum from TBL where slutdatum > '2013-02-21' 
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0,    
DATEDIFF(dd, 0, slutdatum)) ORDER BY sdate DESC) * 100 from tbl
```

How do I make one query that produces two columns, date and percentage for the last 7 days?

Comment: Please explain more. what output exactly u need?

Comment: In order to do math your individual queries need to return a single value.

Comment: @Slint - Which date do you want to show?  Do you want percentages for rows where `rdate=sdate`?

Comment: I have a case list. Each case that gets to support is registered with datetime and some other things. When you close the case the finish time gets registered along with the status closed instead of new or open. I wold like to have a query that gets a break/fix ratio. So lets say that there is 10 new cases to day and i only close three of all cases in my case list. Then for that day the break/fix ratio would be 30% fix ratio. I'm aware that the break/fix ratio dont work if I close more cases then the number of incoming cases but in that situation i would the break/fix ratio to be 100%.

Comment: @PM77-1 The two dates are not related to each other. One is Register datetime and one is Close datetime. It's count all post with slutdatum of date 2013-03-01 count all post with regdate of date 2013-03-01. Take slutdatum (closedate) / regdate * 100 = percentage. Produce two columns one for the date and one for the percentage.

Comment: @PM77-1
Aaa, single value. Of course! 
Then somthing like this might work;
Select TOP 7 DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, regdate)) AS thedate (select count(*) as sum1 from workTB where regdate > '2013-02-21' GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, regdate))) / (select count(*) as sum2 from TBL where slutdatum > '2013-02-21' GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, slutdatum))) * 100 From TBL ORDER BY thedate DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will be comparing events that happen **on the same day**, we can **JOIN** on the date but we will need `FULL OUTER JOIN` to include days when there were only breaks or only fixes.

Here's the updated code:

```
SELECT COALESCE(reg.rdate,cl.sdate) as [Date], ISNULL(reg.sum, 0) as [Registered], ISNULL(cl.sum, 0) as [Closed], 
       CASE WHEN cl.sum IS NULL THEN 0
            WHEN ISNULL(cl.sum,0) > ISNULL(reg.sum,0) THEN 100 
            ELSE CONVERT(float,cl.sum)/reg.sum*100 END as [Percentage]  
FROM 

(SELECT regdate AS rdate, COUNT(regdate) as sum 
FROM TBL where regdate > CONVERT(datetime,'20130221',112) 
GROUP BY regdate ) reg 

FULL OUTER JOIN 

(SELECT slutdatum AS sdate, COUNT(slutdatum) as sum 
FROM TBL WHERE slutdatum > CONVERT(datetime,'20130221',112)
GROUP BY slutdatum) cl

ON (reg.rdate=cl.sdate)
ORDER BY COALESCE(reg.rdate,cl.sdate);
```

I created SQL Fiddle with the test data so you can experiment with the code:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58a33/1.

Comment: It don't work and I really dont know where to tweak. It says that reg.rdate multipart identifier could not be bound.
Then there is some issiu with the order (inkorrect syntax Exspecting ')', EXEPT, OR UNION

Comment: When I was just starting to understand your previous code you presented me with this! Wow It's really spot on what I was looking for. The first code was a good example that took me a little bit further in SQL  coding. I think I understand the concept of it. I have some more to learn from the last post thou. Any how the SQL fiddle site was really helpful and as I said you last code was spot on! Thanks for your help PM 77-1!

Answer (score 0):

You can use (SELECT ...) like a table. So, try  SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...) as A, (SELECT ...) as B

Now you can use values from A and B in the same formula.

Comment: ... and in the absence of `WHERE` clause he'll be getting a **Cartesian Join**.

Comment: I've tried this;
Select TOP 7 * From 

(SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, regdate)) AS rdate, COUNT(*) as regsum FROM workTB where regdate > '2013-02-21' 
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, regdate))) AS A, 

(SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, slutdatum)) AS sdate, COUNT(*) as slutsum 
FROM workTB 
WHERE slutdatum > '2013-02-21' 
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, slutdatum)))  AS B
ORDER BY rdate DESC

But the order is mucked up and also the group by?